# Remember shared folder on server

Tags: sharing, folders, file-sharing

I'm new to Mac.

I have files on a shared folder that I often access and every time I restart the computer I have to go to Finder->go->connect to server->fill in the information and press connect. Is there a way I can always have the shared folder available and have the computer remember my password for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "+" button to the right of the pathname text field will save the path for you.

Also, when you authenticate to the server, there should be a checkbox beneath the username/password fields.  The checkbox should read "Remember this password in my keychain."  If that's selected when you successfully authenticate, then your credentials will be saved to your keychain and used automatically when you try to connect.

Comment: and you cann add the option to add the server-connection to autostart (System Settings -> Users -> Start Objects) - because he talks about restarting his Computer ;)

Comment: @YoshiBotX how do you do this?  I can't find System Settings

Comment: @Celeritas YoshiBotX means "Login Items."  With the server already mounted, launch System Preferences > Users & Groups.  Under your user, select "Login Items."  Add a login item and select the already-connected server.  Then, whenever you log in, your Mac will try to connect to the server using the credentials you've stored in your Keychain.

Comment: System Settings -> Users & Groups -> Your UserName (Left Column) -> Login Items (right Column, right Tab)
-> Click "+" and simply add the mounted volume to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Preferring to limit what I trust to KeyChain for this type of thing, I just make an alias (finder, file menu, make an alias) of the shared folder and park it on the desktop (or in another local folder.) Clicking on the alias will bring up the login window with the name used when the folder was aliased filled in, I type in my password, the share is mounted and I'm in the folder. If the share is already mounted, it just takes me to the folder.

If you use the "save my password" checkbox, clicking on the alias will just take you to the folder.